# Why I have to do c-48? and what does \a and %2.f mean?

Tags: c, visual-studio, performance, variables, calculator

This programm is a simple calculater.
At first sorry for my bad english, i want wo know whats the meaning of '\a' & '%2.f'
I know %f is for double but why '2.' in front of 'f'?
Right before the end we set 'dgt' to 'c-48' i want to know why '-48'
I am a informatic student and I am at the beginning, you have some special tips for me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Simple Calculator: \nValid inputs are +-*/=and digits 0,...,9\n");
   printf("Your input: \n");
   double r = 0.0;
   double dgt = 0.0;
   char lst_opt = '+';
   const int nxt_dgt = 1;
   const int nxt_opt = 2;
   int nxt_npt = nxt_dgt;
   while (1)
   {
       char c = _getch();
       switch (c)
       {
        case '+': 
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
            if (nxt_npt != nxt_opt)
            {
                printf("\a");
                break;
            }
            printf("%c", c);
            lst_opt = c;
            nxt_npt = nxt_dgt;
            break;
        case '=': 
            if (nxt_npt != nxt_opt)
            {
               printf("\a");
               break;
            }
               printf("\n=%.2f", r); //double, but why .2?
               nxt_npt = nxt_opt;
               break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            if (nxt_npt != nxt_dgt)
            {
               printf("\a");
               break;
            }
            printf("%c", c);
            dgt = c-48;
            switch (lst_opt)
            {
              case '+': r += dgt; break;
              case '-': r -= dgt; break;
              case '*': r *= dgt; break;
              case '/': r /= dgt; break;
            }
            nxt_npt = nxt_opt;
            break;
            }
      }
_getch();
}
```

Comment: 48 should be '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\a is use to make a sound
c-48 : as stated in the comment, 48 is the ascii value of character ´0’. So c-48 convert ascii character ‘0’ .. ´9’ to integer value 0 ... 9
In printed documentation you could see that %2.f means that you print a floating value with at least 2 characters at the left of decimal point and no decimal eg :
2.643 -> ´ 2’
123.4 -> ´123’

Answer (score 1):

- What does `\a` means?

Like `\n`, an escape character meaning "newline", it is an escape character too, meaning "alert", which makes a beep sound when "printed".
You can find informations (including other special escape characters) [Here](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/c_Notes/tips_printf.html).

- Why minus 48?

In the code, it is trying to get a integer from a character. Instead of doing things like `if(c == '3') i = 3;`, it uses how the character '0'~'9' are ordered in the [ACSII Table](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp#:%7E:text=The%20ASCII%20Character%20Set,character%20set%20containing%20128%20characters.). You can see that, '0'~'9' are orded tightly from 48 to 57. that is, `'0' - 48` produces a result of 0, and the same for other ones.

- `%2.f`

You know `%f` are used for printing a `float` variable, that's good, however there is more to know. You are able to format how the variables are going to be printed.
The `2.` stands for "Print the float number at least 2 character wide, also none
of the decimal places should be printed". More `printf()` formatting informations [Here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 1):

> whats the meaning of '\a'

This one is actually somewhat obscure.  The escape sequence `\a` appearing in a character constant or string literal represents a character that, when delivered to a terminal, causes an alert signal to be sounded and / or displayed without changing the output position.  Details of the signal are environment specific, but it might produce a beep or cause the screen to flash, or similar.  This is rarely used these days.

> & '%2.f' I know %f is for double but why '2.' in front of 'f'?

For information about `printf` format strings, you would do well to look up good reference material -- online manual pages (search keywords "man printf") would be my recommendation, though the language specification documents are the ultimate authority.  Textbooks and tutorials do not typically cover all the details, which are many.

If you did that, you would find that the `2` is a (minimum) field width, and the `.` is shorthand for `.0`, a precision specification instructing `printf` to emit zero fractional digits.

> Right before the end we set 'dgt' to 'c-48' i want to know why '-48'

It is essential to understand that there is a difference between digit *characters* and the numbers they represent.  48 is the ASCII code for the character `'0'`, and C requires each subsequent decimal digit to have a code one greater than the previous, so, **supposing that the implementation uses ASCII-compatible character codes**, `dgt-48` converts any decimal digit character to its corresponding numeric value.

However, this would be more safely and more idiomatically expressed as `dgt - '0'`.  That's clearer, in that it at least provides a clue about what's going on, and it works even on implementations that use character encodings that are not ASCII compatible.